# PCRE Regex - exclude some cases

Tags: regex, pcre

```
$regex = /(^)(\[(.*)\]) (.*)$/;
```

Regex takes all mesages which looks like this:

```
[Help] John: ...
```

Problem is that chat has messages which look like this:

```
[      ] Tehnical information: ...
[ >Important< ] ...
[ >>>  ] ...
[ <<<  ] ...
```

So, I need to exclude messages, where:

- Only spaces and/or signs `'>', '<'`
- Only word Important or Important with spaces and signs `'>', '<'`

Spaces and signs `'>', '<'` can exists in other cases and if there is other characters such numbers or something then this messages should be taken.

```
[General] John: Hi!
[ > BUFF < ] ...
[ >>> 45] ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^(?!\[[ <>]*(?:Important)?[ <>]*\])(\[(.*)\]) (.*)$/
```

- `(?!)` - a negative lookahead to ensure that
- `\[\]` - the thing inside the square brackets is not
- `[ <>]*(?:Important)?[ <>]*` - just a variable number (`*`) of spaces, `<` and `>` with an optional (`?`) occurrence of the word `Important` inside.

Comment: Um, in case of "Important": space and '>', '<' count can be very...dynamic

Comment: @user64675, ok fixed (assuming you mean vary by number and not arangement).

Comment: Vary by number AND arangement ((

Comment: @user64675, ok, fixed.

Comment: The optional group enclosed with identical `[ <>]*` subpatterns (`[ <>]*(?:Important)?[ <>]*`) loses a bit of performance to a more linear `[ <>]*(?:Important[ <>]*)?`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, no it doesn't (at least not asymptotically significant loss if any at all). The bracktracking will be the same in both cases.

Comment: No, it won't be the same, my pattern involves fewer backtracking steps. See the regex debugger page. However, the difference is indeed insignificant.

Comment: And FYI: In PCRE, you do not need to escape `]` outside the character class.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, can you write an example line where your regex has a better-than-constant-amount-of-steps-reduction superiority.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, The way I see it, your regex is slightly better for positives, mine is slightly better for negatives. Both by a very small constant number of steps.

Comment: And as I said, the difference is insignificant. No need to spend too much time on it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it's just that your wording was a little confusing for me. By calling your approach *"more linear"* it sounded to me as if you are suggesting they are different in terms of asymptotic complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest

```
^(\[(?![ <>]*(?:Important[ <>]*)?])(.*)]) (.*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iQ9nW8/2)

The `(?![ <>]*(?:Important[ <>]*)?])` negative lookahead will fail your regex match if there are just spaces inside or if there is `Important` word preceded or followed with any spaces, `<` or `>` in any order.

Note that the lookahead is placed right after the opening `[` which reduces redundant backtracking if placed before and included `[`.

Pattern details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\[` - Start of Group 1, opening `[`
- `(?![ <>]*(?:Important[ <>]*)?])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the following is matched:

  - `[ <>]*` - 0+ characters: space, `<` or `>`
  - `(?:Important[ <>]*)?` - 1 or 0 sequences of

    - `Important` - literal word
    - `[ <>]*` -  0+ characters: space, `<` or `>`
  - `]` - closing `]`
- `(.*)` - Group 2, matching 0+ characters other than a newline
- `])` - End of Group 1, `]` matches closing `]`
- `(.*)` - Group 3, matching 0+ characters other than a newline
- `$` - end of string